# jQuery: Detect a click on a changed class name that is NOT the original class

Tags: jquery, class, button, detect

I have this button that changes its class from maximize to minimize. Originally it has a maximize class but on click it changes to a minimize. Now I want to catch the click on minimize and only minimize.

Take a look at my code below:

```
$('.button-maximize').off('click').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('button-maximize').addClass('button-minimize');
});
```

So this will change the class to minimize. Obviously I need event delegation to catch the event.

So I do this next:

```
$('.button-wrap').off('click').on('click', '.button-minimize:not(.button-maximize)', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

To clarify `button-wrap` is the parent. So my problem is that this **alert('test');** fires when I first click on the maximize button. How do I tell jQuery that I only want it to fire if the button doesn't have a class "button-maximize"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the click either way and check it.

```
$('.button-wrap').on('click', '.button-minimize, .button-maximize', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('button-maximize')) {
    $(this).removeClass('button-maximize').addClass('button-minimize');
  } else {
    alert('test');
  }
});
```

EDIT Response to comment: This does bascially the same thing but the key is the event is attached to the wrapper.

```
$('.button-wrap').on('click', '.button-maximize', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('button-maximize').addClass('button-minimize');
}).on('click', '.button-minimize', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: I find your solution closest to what I need for it doesn't add any additional attributes and keeps the code pretty clean. Is there no way to modify my code in a way to get it to work. That's out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass("button-maximize")){
 alert('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two events in same button you could give your button an identifier `id` fpr exampel `button-id` then attach click event to it :

```
$(".button-wrap").on("click", "#button-id", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('button-minimize')){
         alert('test');
    }else{
         $(this).removeClass('button-maximize').addClass('button-minimize');
    }
});
```

And because button toggle between the two classes you could check if the button has class `button-minimize` (what men hasn't maximize class) using `hasClass()` method then show the alert, else remove `maximize` and add `minimize`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to achieve this. The easiest way probably looks something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/x4q3nwyL/1/

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('maximize')) {
      alert('test');
    }
    $this.toggleClass('maximize minimize');
});
```

No need to unbind. On click you will check if it is a maximize button and do your thing. After that you will toggle both the minimize and maximize classes. This will cause it to switch between a minimize and a maximize button on each click. I guess that is what you are after...